# TFS Online/VSO Build with Common Assemblies

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

I was wondering if anyone could help.We have the following project structure in our company :

- Code/Common
- Code/Project1
- Code/Project2
- etc...

When the Common Project builds, it has a PostBuild Event that copies all the relevant files into the Code/Common/Binaries folder. Then all the other Projects reference the Common components in this folder.

However, what we are struggling with is that when TFS Online checks-out the solution it does so to c:\a\src and the Common binaries are placed in c:\a\src\Binaries. Now, when the other projects (Project1 etc) do their build it cannot find the Common Assemblies, as not only are they removed, but the paths are different from what it expects them to be in c:\a\src\Common\Binaries instead of c:\a\src\Binaries.

Is there anyway to tell the build server to not delete those files in the "Binaries" directory and to specify the folder location to checkout to? Or how one one go about solving such a problem?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A build server is a transient thing, you cannot rely on files to be there.

You need to either Create Nuget Packages for you common output and then consume these in your other projects (the 'proper' way), or you will need to check your dependencies into source control after each build so you can then reference them in subsequent builds (the 'really frowned apon' way).

Comment: How would I go about doing the Nuget approach as these are packages for our company and not for everyone. Also, does VSO have the ability to consume these custom feeds. 

Do you have any articles on how about to do this?

Comment: you will need to create your own feed and then post to there. you can look at http://NuGetter.codeplex.com for how to create NuGet Packages as part of the TFS build process.